# Animation In Jquery Using .html()

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am recently working on an animation project, just here to ask a question about it.

For Ex: I have a variable 'MONEY'  which I have to display in `<p>` tag after every operation performed on it.

Here's a brief overview:

```
var MONEY=0;

for(var i=1;i<=10;i++){
   MONEY+=500;
   $('p').html(''+MONEY);
}
```

Now, My question is How do I animate `<p>` tag, (i.e with some text effects, so that every time it is displayed animation should happen).

Right Now,
I have added animation to

like below:-

```
p{
 //some animation
}
```

but this doesn't work, Any help?

Comment: What kind of animation are you trying to do? Count up animation? And can you post your animation code?

Comment: Count Up Animation would do, but you can have a look at https://textillate.js.org/ .

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the paragraph in the javascript part:

```js
var MONEY=0;

for(var i=1;i<=10;i++){
    MONEY+=500;
    $('p').addClass('anim');
    $('p').html(''+MONEY);
}
```

the associated CSS:

```css
p.anim{
    transform:translateY(300px);<br>
    transition:0.5s in all;<br>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I m afraid to say that it just doesn't work.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could just paste a link to JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("p").change(function(){
  $(this).animate({
    left: '250px',
    height: '+=150px',
    width: '+=150px'
  });
});
```

You could try this code. Animations can be done simpler with jQuery.